# Understanding why f(z) can be differentiable, but not analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I'm working through a practice exam and can only do part of this problem.

Let $f(z) = x^3 + iy^3$. Find all points where the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied, and give a brief explanation of why $f(z)$ is differentiable but not analytic at these points.

I can do the first part:

$u(x,y)=x^3$ and $v(x,y)=v^3$

$u_x=3x^2$, $v_y=3y^2$

$u_y=0, v_x=0$

So $u_y=-v_x$, but the Cauchy-Riemann equations are only satisfied, that is $u_x=v_y$ or $3x^2=3y^2$when $x=y$.

How do I address being differentiable and not analytic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition a complex function is analytic at a point if it is differentiable not only at the point itself, but in its neighborhood. If you want formally, a function is analytic in $z_0$ if there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that the function is differentiable at every point $z$ which satisfies $|z-z_0|<\epsilon$. So being differentiable at a point and being analytic at a point are two different things.

For example, let's look at your function. You found it is differentiable only at the points of the set $\{x+iy: x^2=y^2\}$. Easy to see that this set has no interior points. If you want formally, let's assume $x^2=y^2$ for some number $z=x+iy$, and take any $\epsilon>0$. Then look at the point $w=(x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}+iy)$. The distance of that point from $z$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ but $(x+\frac{\epsilon}{2})^2 \ne y^2$, so $f$ is not differentiable at $w$. Hence there is no neighborhood of $z$ in which $f$ is differentiable at every point, so $f$ is not analytic at $z$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I probably should have included definitions in my question.  How do I apply the definition to this particular f(z)?

Comment: I edited my answer. Oh, and you also asked about why $f$ is differentiable. Well, there is a theorem that if a function has continuous partial derivatives (here I mean partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$) and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at a point then it is differentiable at that point. So your $f$ is differentiable at the points $z=x+iy$ where $x^2=y^2$ but as I showed it isn't analytic at these points.

Comment: In this context it is weird to use the word analytic when you meant holomorphic (complex differentiable on an open set)

Comment: @reuns, it's a matter of definitions. When I took a course on complex analysis we defined holomorphic and analytic as synonyms. I know that some define them as two different things-holomorphic is complex differentiable in neighborhood, analytic is if you can write the function as power series around the point that converges in its neighborhood. After all it doesn't matter because in complex analysis the two definitions are equivalent. (which isn't trivial of course, but for that reason many people define holomorphic and analytic as the same thing).